# Search using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

i have code search use knockout.js

```
        function UserListModel(list) {
        var self = this;
        self.searchData = ko.observable();
        //self.pagedList = ko.utils.pagedObservableArray(list);
        self.pagedList = ko.utils.pagedObservableArray({ data: list, showFirstLast: true });

        var allData = list;
        self.clearSearch = function () {
            self.searchData("");
            self.pagedList.allData(allData);
        };
        self.search = function () {
            var filterData = allData;
            if (self.searchData() != "") {
                filterData = $.grep(allData, function (e) {
                    return e.Name.search(self.searchData()) >= 0;
                });
            }
            self.pagedList.allData(filterData);
        };
    }
```

When searching it can only search exact input text in upper case or lower case. I want it to be able to search relative both upper case and lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your search term and the string you are searching in [to lower case](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp). Then you will have the case insensitive search you want.